# How do I keep the time on a server (virtual machine) updated over time?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, clock

I have a virtual machine running headless in my machine. When I start it for the first time, the result of `date` command is correct. But after about a day or 2, I SSH into it and the `date` command has become late. Like when I tried today, it's already 5 days behind. A restart of the machine fixes this issue (but I don't want to restart all the time).

How do I keep the time/date updated on my server virtual machine over time?

I've noticed this behavior with CentOS 7 and Turnkey Linux (Debian 7) guest OSes. The host is a Mac mini and I'm virtualizing with VirtualBox.

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions on Linux? Are you running NTP on the guest?

Comment: @Gilles I'm not sure. How do I check that? I'm currently running vanilla Turnkey Linux Core.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/169024/how-can-i-tell-if-the-virtualbox-guest-additions-were-installed-on-an-ubuntu-vm and http://superuser.com/questions/181341/how-to-check-if-ntp-adjusted-system-time-on-linux

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your comments, I think it resolved my issue: installing guest additions and ntp. But I have to observe it for a few days. I didn't know that guest additions was needed to get the time updated.

Comment: @Gilles Okay, I think your comment did the trick. Perhaps convert it to an answer so I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install NTP in your VM and let it take care of that?

If you were using VMware the best thing to do would be to install `vmware-tools` which provides automatic sync of time.  However, I don't know whether a similar package exists for VirtualBox.